# Prevent Asp.net application to show password in HTTP headers

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

As the title goes I'm stuck with a problem. As whenever I login to my portfolio website and test it's http header through firebug NET option I find out that I can see my **password** in POST request. As I don't know how severe this venerability or not. but I'm quite confused regarding

1. Why HTTP header shows POST fields
2. Is it ok to go with it as i find out that Facebook hadn't done any work for this
3. How to stop showing password post field in ASP.NET C# and PHP as i work on both domains
4. As what i guess HTTP Header works on client side(Browsers) but What works on server side. (Pardon me for my idiocy but I'm quite curious )

Below is screenshot of my problem.

[image]

Comment: It's ok. That's how your debugger shows it.

Comment: Won't it's a security breach ? Or how to prevent from this ?

Comment: No, your security is ok. Almost all modern browsers have debuggers that allow to inspect requests data. It's not your application's fault. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok and what works on server side to store these information ?

Comment: @SaadSuri We don't know how your server is written, so we can't answer "what works on server side to store these information?".

Comment: No I meant to ask which protocol like HTTP Headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form post contains the password in the clear, but if a lower layer is encrypted, this doesn't matter. This is why login should always be conducted over a *secure* HTTPS connection.

If you're allowing logins over insecure (HTTP) connections, your worries are justified. Get yourself a certificate and require HTTPS.

Comment: But you can find the same thing on Facebook too. Doesn't facebook work on HTTPS ?

Comment: @SaadSuri Yes. Facebook uses HTTPS. They have a certificate. The line is secure. Just as described in my answer.